# SCP file between 2 servers that go through few servers

Tags: ssh, proxy, scp

I want to copy a file from server-a to server-d but I can access server-d only from server-b and then to server-c. server-a can only access server-b, server-b can only access server-c, server-c can only access server-d..

Currently I do it like this:

```
server-a> scp /tmp/file.txt user@server-b
server-a> ssh user@server-b
server-b> scp /tmp/file.txt user@server-c
server-b> ssh user@server-c
server-c> scp /tmp/file.txt user@server-d
```

This could be through 5,6,7,.. servers

Can I do this is one command?

Answer (score 5):

You need the `ProxyCommand`, see the [man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+unstable+sid&format=html&locale=en). Here's an example:

```
Host serverB
HostName serverA.com
User someuser
ProxyCommand ssh -q serverB -W %h:%p  # -W is supported by a recent OpenSSH
# or for older versions or other implementations
# ProxyCommand ssh -q serverB nc %h %p
```

This allows you to type `ssh serverB` and you connect to serverA which then connects to serverB. This can easily be extended to work with  host. It will work with `scp` the same way it does for `ssh`.

Comment: I only can use the ssh command not the `~/.ssh/config` file. Does this command should work `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh user@server-d\" user@server-c" user@server-b` ?

Comment: Should work. You can also use alternate config file through the `-F` option.

Answer (score 1):

your best bet is probably to build up tunnels, and then `cat` the file through oll these tunnels:

```
cat file.txt | ssh -A -t user@server-b \
   "cat | ssh -A user@server-c         \
      \"cat | ssh -A user@server-d     \
         \\\"cat > /tmp/file.txt\\\"   \
      \"                               \
   "
```